# Can we deduce that any additive map from V to W, over the field $R$ is actually a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I showed as an exercise that for an additive function $T: V\to W$, if $T(u+v)= T(u)+T(v)$, then if the field is the rationals, we get that the linearity implies scalar multiplication, i.e.  $T(qv)=qT(v)$ for all q in rationals and v in V and so T is actually a linear transformation. My question is, if the field was all of R, can we conclude the same thing? I think not, but is there a way to extend this result by maybe introducing limiting procedures into the vector space? Thanks!

Comment: If $T$ is continuous, then yes: it must be a linear transformation.  See [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation).  Also, I'm pretty sure this has been asked on this site before.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957274/fab-fafb-but-f-is-not-linear?noredirect=1&lq=1).