# $g(x)=\lim _{t \to 0} \frac{f(x+t)-f(x-t)}{t}$,prove that there is a $c\in(a,b)$ ,such that $g(c)\geqslant0$

Tags: analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$ (not necessarily derivable) and satisfy $f(a)<f(b)$. At the same  time, the limit $g(x)=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x+t)-f(x-t)}{t}$ exists for all $x\in(a,b)$.

Prove that there is a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $g(c)\geqslant0$.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Also, note that $g(x) = 2 × f'(x)$

Comment: @Chief VS: $f'(x)$ can fail to exist at some points. For example, if $f(x) = |x|,$ then $f$ is continuous everywhere and $g(0) = 0,$ but $f'(0)$ does not exist. In fact, $f$ can be continuous everywhere and $g$ can exist everywhere, and $f'$ can fail to exist on a dense set of points (indeed, even sets having cardinality $c$ in every interval; even more, even sets having Hausdorff dimension $1$ in every interval). For more details, see my comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2703992/13130).

Comment: I probably shouldn't do this, but your question is Lemma 1 on p. 708 of [*The first symmetric derivative*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2314269) by Charles Edward Aull [American Mathematical Monthly 74 #6 (June-July 1967), pp. 708-711].

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, Gotcha, i didn't knew that, thanks.