# Is there non-zero vector with bounded orbit if the set of vectors with unbounded is residual and open in Banach space $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $T:X\to X$ be a bounded operator  on  Banach space $X$ such that $A= \{x: \{T^n(x)\}_{n=0}^\infty \text{ is unbounded } \}$ be  residual in $X$.

In my research, the set of vector $x\in X$ with bounded orbit is closed i.e. $A$ is open set in $X$. Clearly orbit of $x=0$ is bounded. Is there a non-zero vector $x\in X$ that its orbit is bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T$ could be $\lambda Id$ with $|\lambda|>1\implies A=X\backslash\{0\}$.

**edit:** I answer to this: "it seems that if the set of non-zero vector in $X$ with unbounded orbit is open and residual, then the set of non-zero vector with bounded orbit is empty.".

**claim:** Let $X$ a  infinite Hilbert space then every normal and compact operator $T$ (with an eigenvalues of less than one length ) has a non-zero vector with bounded orbit and $A$ is open and residual.

**proof:** By the spectral theorem there exists an O.N. base $(e_j)$ such that $Te_j=\lambda_je_j$, now its easy to see that $v\in A^c$ (i.e. has a bounded orbit) if and only if $\langle v,e_j \rangle=0$ for every $e_j$ s.t. $|\lambda_j|>1$.

By the infinity dimension, the eigenvalues goes to zero so there exists $e_j$ s.t. $|e_j|\le1$ and these vector stays in $A^c$.

Now we have only to prove that $A$ is open and residual:

I'll prove that $A^c$ is closed. Because A is a metrizable space i can work with the classical sequences. Let $v^k\in A^c$ that converges to some $v\in X$ then: $$\langle v,e_j\rangle=\lim \langle v^k,e_j\rangle=\lim 0=0 \;\text{ for every for every $e_j$ s.t. $|\lambda_j|>1$} $$ $$\implies v\in A^c\implies A^c\text{ is closed.}$$

Now, [because](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109162/understanding-residual-sets) $A$ is open, we only need to prove that its dense. By the hypothesis exists  $e_j$ with $|\lambda_j|>1$ and if $v\in A^c$ then $v+\varepsilon e_j\in A$ for every small $\varepsilon>0\implies A$ is dense.

Comment: Thanks. But $A= X\setminus \{0\}$ means that there is no non-zero vector with bounded orbit. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, in fact you need additional hypothesis for operator $T$ (if you want a non-zero vector with bounded orbit).

Comment: Is there such hypothesis? I think the set of non-zero vector with bounded orbit may be empty set.

Comment: If $T$ is a compact and normal then its diagonalizable . Now if your space is infinite dimensional surely the  eigenvalues $(\lambda_j)$goes to zero $\implies$ the eigenvector associated with the eigenvalues s.t. $|\lambda_j|<1$ will have bounded orbit.

Comment: In the case of $T$ is compact and normal on infinite dimensional space $X$, is it true that the set of vectors with unbounded orbit is an open and residual in $X$?
.

Comment: do you want an answer for this particular case ? (note that now $X$ is an Hilbert space)

Comment: My research is dynamical system and I does have few information about operators on infinite -dimensional  space. Some example that I saw in this subject, it seems that if the set of non-zero vector in $X$ with unbounded orbit is open and residual, then the set of non-zero vector with bounded orbit is empty. I am so thankful if you help me to know that it is true or not.

Comment: I edit my answer. There are some settings where your last statement is false.