# What does $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x_0)-g(x_0-h)}{h}$ represent

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

When working through an analysis problem involving derivaties I have found myself at this limit :

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x_0)-g(x_0-h)}{h}$
Doing some testing with well-defined functions leads me to believe this may be some sort of alternative definition of a derivative, can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Replace $h$ by $-h$.

Comment: In terms of solving the limit, am I allowed to just replace $h$ with $-h$?

Comment: this is the definition for the 'left side derivative' at point $x_0$
EDIT: nevermind, this is only the case for $h>0 $

Comment: In the definition of the limit $h$ lies in a neighborhood of 0 (that doesn't necessarily include 0)  i.e. $0<|h|<\delta.$  $h$ can be positive or negative, and we should have no problem replacing $h$ with $-h$ in this limit.

Comment: You posted the same question less than an hour before you posted this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4369295/differentiability-in-relation-to-strange-limit  Please don't do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t=-h$. As $h$ tends to zero $t$ does so as well. Therefore the limit is equivalent to
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{g(x_0)-g(x_0+t)}{-t} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{g(x_0+t)-g(x_0)}{t}$$
and if this limit exists it equals $g'(x_0)$.

Comment: $-h$ is okey for left hand derivative ?

Comment: @AmitMittal I'm not completely sure what you mean. If $h$ approaches $0$ so it can take both positive and negative values then so can $-h$. If you wanted a one sided limit you'd have to say $h>0$ or $h<0$ to achieve this.

Comment: yes i asking for the same. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the insight.

Comment: @HungaryGoose You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically this represents (in the derivative) that you are not starting at the point $x_0$ and taking a little increment t, indeed, you are parting at the end of the increment (t) and you are form this start point to the point $x_0$ (the narrow reverse its sign) and then, when you do t tends to zero, the star point of this narrow is reaching more and more and more to the point $x_0$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).