# Is there a additive non-linear non-complex map?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{F}\neq \mathbb{C}$. Give an example of a non-linear map $T:V\to W$ such that \begin{equation}T(x+y) = T(x)+T(y), \forall x,y\in V.\end{equation}

I asked myself this question when I was resolving an excercise list os Linear Algebra. This example is pretty easy when $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$. We take $V=W=\mathbb{C}$ and $T:z\mapsto \bar{z}$, and we have that $T(\lambda z) = \bar{\lambda}T(z)$. However, I couldn't find any examples for non-complex vector spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a nonlinear additive function on R imply a Hamel basis of R?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366010/does-a-nonlinear-additive-function-on-r-imply-a-hamel-basis-of-r)

Comment: @FlybyNight but that's specifically asking about $\Bbb R$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The OP said they "couldn't find any examples for non-complex vector spaces." The reals are such an example. A simple Google search of "additive non linear functions" turns up lots of hits, e.g. on stackexchange, stackoverflow and some other sites.

Comment: @FlybyNight still, there is no one source that answers the question sufficiently.  That seems like enough of a reason to leave it open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every such map with $\Bbb F = \Bbb Q$ will be linear.  The same will be true for finite fields.

With $\Bbb F = \Bbb R$, this may or may not be true, depending on your axioms (see the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation) for more).

If $\Bbb F$ is an extension of $\Bbb Q$ with degree $1<[\Bbb F: \Bbb Q] < \infty$, then such maps exist (for example: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$).  This same idea works if $\Bbb F$ satisfies $1 < [\Bbb F: \Bbb F'] < \infty$ for *any* subfield $\Bbb F'$, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a slight variation on your counterexample. Consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) = \{a+b\sqrt{2}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. Then $T: \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}),\ a+b\sqrt{2}\mapsto a-b\sqrt{2}$ is such a non-linear map.

Answer (score 1):

A discontinuous additive function $a\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is non-linear map of a linear space $\Bbb R$ over a field $\Bbb R$ to itself. Observe that any additive map is linear, if the field of scalars is $\Bbb Q$.