# what is a basis for $\ell^p$?

Tags: functional-analysis

For the familiar vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have the following standard orthonormal basis: $\{e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n\}$.  Where $e_1 = (1, 0, \ldots, 0)$ and so on...

For $\ell^p$ would we have $\{x_1 = (1, 0, 0, \ldots), x_2 = (0, 1, 0, \ldots), \ldots, x_n = (0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots), \ldots\}$?

Would this be orthonormal as well?

Comment: When you say basis... what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Span the entire space (all of $l^p$), of course.

Comment: Yeah, but in what sense?

Comment: See this question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194189/a-hamel-basis-for-l-p.

Comment: Would the ideas from $\mathbb{R}^n$ not work here?  I was hoping in the same sense.

Comment: Dimensions act more or less like cardinality. Since when the things you know about cardinality of finite sets make sense about cardinality of infinite sets?

Answer (score 3):

**No**, this is not a basis.

Consider $p = 2$, and the sequence $s_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Then, this is in $l^p$, but this is not expressible as a linear combination of your basis, as any finite sum of your $x_i$ will eventually have every coordinate be $0$, but every coordinate of $s$ is nonzero.

Comment: Generally speaking, how would you construct a basis for one of these infinite spaces?

Comment: Huh??? How would that be a basis for $\ell^\infty$?

Comment: I wouldn't. You cannot write an explicit basis for this space; the question Dimitris proved explains why.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, it's not, I mixed up $l^\infty$ with the vector space of compact sequences.

Answer (score 0):

This set does not "span" the space according to one of the standard definitions of "span", i.e. not every point in the space is a linear combination of finitely many members of this set. Nor is it a "basis" when that term is defined by relying on that notion of "span".

But it **is** what is called an "orthonormal basis" in the case in which $p=2$. As far as being orthonormal is concerned, just compute the inner products. That's all there is to that.

The definition of "orthonormal basis" requires that every member of $\ell^2$ be representable as a sum of an *infinite* linear combination of members of the set. Whether a sum of infinitely many things exists depends on which kind of convergence you're talking about. The fact that various different kinds exist is the reason why people are somewhat careful and cautious about these things. In $\ell^p,$ the kind of convergence you're talking about is defined by the $\ell^p$ norm of the difference between the limit and the thing approaching the limit going to $0.$

In order to speak of orthonormality in a normed space, it must be an inner product space. Norms that come from inner products satisfy the parallelogram law. The $\ell^p$ norm does not satisfy the parallelogram law except when $p=2.$

Answer (score 0):

It is no basis, because every basis of an infinite-dimensional Banach space is uncountable as a consequence of the Baire category Theorem, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem