# Benefits of choosing a Hamel bases for $L^p$ including a specific linearly independent subset

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, hamel-basis

According to the book I am studying (Royden & Fitzpatrick):

> We can infer from Zorn's Lemma that every linear space possesses a Hamel basis.

A Hamel Basis is defined as a subset $\mathcal{B} $ of a linear space $X$ provided each vector in $X$ is expressible as a unique $\bf{finite}$ linear combination of vectors in $\mathcal{B}$.

When I first read about the concept of Hamel bases (compared to other sets referred to as basis), I recognized that bases of finite spaces are Hamel basis, and that, for example, $\{x^k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ is a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}[x]$, the infinite-dimensional space of polynomials with real coefficients.

As comments have pointed out, there might not be a Hamel basis that is explicit to state for other  common infinite-dimensional linear spaces ($\ell^p$ or $L^p$) - their Hamel bases would need to be uncountable.

However, even if we cannot explicitly characterize the whole basis, could we choose one that includes a specific (countable) set of vectors as a subset, given they are 'independent'? (For example, include $ \{x^k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ in the Hamel basis for $L^p([a,b])$). If so, what are the applications of this fact?

Comment: When the dimension is continuum, I think there is almost no hope for writing such explicit basis. Choice of one that includes a specific countable linearly independent set is possible though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Hamel basis for $\ell^p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194189/a-hamel-basis-for-ellp)

Comment: Thank you for the link! I changed the question to ask what (if any) 'benefits' there might be to being able to choose a Hamel basis including a certain linearly independent set of vectors. This is not a duplicate as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes, an arbitrary linearly independent subset $S$ can be extended to a Hamel basis. Just apply Zorn's lemma to the family of all linearly independent sets which contain $S$, ordered by inclusion. The maximal element will be a Hamel basis.

Answer (score 0):

> could we choose one that includes a specific (countable) set of vectors as a subset, given they are 'independent'?

Yes, we can.

> If so, what are the applications of this fact?

None.

Comment: Care to explain the "None"?

Comment: I think "none" is at least an exaggeration, if not just false. For example, a simple application of the fact that we can always extend a linearly independent set to a basis (assuming AC) is the existence of a discontinuous linear functional on any infinite dimensional normed space.