# Why from the point of view of constructive analysis denumerable hamel basis is not suitable for an infinite dimensional Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hamel-basis

We know that for an infinite dimensional Banach Space the Hamel Basis needs to be uncountable. Why is it difficult from the point of view of **constructive analysis** to obtain an Uncountable Hamel Basis for an infinite dimensional Banach Space ?

I have found no resources online regarding the construction of a uncountable hamel basis for **any** infinite dimensional Banach space

Answer (score 1):

Think about how you might create such a basis.  Let's say for $\ell^1$.  You start with the standard unit vectors, whose span merely gives you vectors which have only finitely many non-zero entries.  What do you add next?  Maybe $(\frac1n)$?  Then $(2^{-n})$?  You keep adding things in.  Then you lose track of what is a linear span of what you have previously added.

It is similar to creating a Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$.  Start with $1$, $\sqrt 2$, $\sqrt 3$, $\pi$.  Can we add $e$, or is that already in the linear span of the previous elements?

If you want to make it rigorous, you would want to show that there is a model of set theory in which $\ell^1$ does not have a Hamel basis.  I found this, but it doesn't precisely answer this question.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233359/linear-space-with-hamel-basis-and-the-axiom-of-choice

This seems to answer your question rigorously: [A Hamel basis for $\ell^p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194189/a-hamel-basis-for-ellp)