# $V^{**}$ not isomorphic to V

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I want an example where vector space $V$ is not isomorphic to it's double dual space.

I took space of sequences which have only finitely many non zero elements as $V$ and show that $V^*$ is a space of sequences, which has bigger dimension than $V$. Is there a quick way to show that $V$ and $V^{**}$ aren't isomorphic? Like injective function from $V^*$ to $V^{**}$ (possibly in general case)?

I know that there exist theorem which states that $\dim V \lt \dim V^*$ but I am looking for something easier.

Comment: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/dualspaceinfinite.pdf

Comment: Why the tag functional analysis? Aren't you considering the *algebraic* dual and bidual?

Comment: I have already seen this paper and as I said I am looking for something easier

Comment: @romperextremeabuser If so, then that kind of context is useful to include in your question.

Comment: @romper The dual space of a vector space $V$ of countable dimension is easy to think about in terms of functions over some countable basis of $V$; this amounts to the observation that $V^*$ will be isomorphic to a space of sequences, as you note. The problem is that the same trick does not apply to $V^{*}$ because $V^*$ doesn't have any nice basis; [see this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/194228/81360) for more on that. So, there's no analogous neat way to think of the elements of $V^{**}$

Comment: @romper You might have some luck thinking about the space of terminating sequences over $\Bbb F_2$. In this case, you can think of $V$ as the set of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ and think of $V^*$ as $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$, the set of all subsets. $V^{**}$, I believe, can be thought of as the set of all functions from $f:\mathcal P(\Bbb N) \to \Bbb F_2$ that respect symmetric differences in the sense that $f(A \Delta B) = f(A) + f(B)$

Comment: Bounded sequences with sup-norm should do.

Comment: I think that one needs (some version of) the axiom of choice to produce elements of $V^{**}$ not belonging to (the canonical image of) $V$. This means, that the answer to your question is not as easy as you might hope.