# Can we reproduce a basis of a vector space of all sequences?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, axiom-of-choice

Can we reproduce a basis of a vector space of all sequences?(if exists since by every vector space has a basis, but can we reproduce it)

Comment: I think you mean "produce" not "reproduce," but the usual term would be "construct."  I would guess that the answer is "No," but I don't know how to prove it.  (I assume you mean construct it without using the axiom of choice.)

Comment: The general questions is discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86762/finding-a-basis-of-an-infinite-dimensional-vector-space but your specific example is not mentioned.

Comment: It's already  hard to even think of describing a basis that has to consist of uncountably many members, when the total description has to fit into finitely many words ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Describing a basis with uncountably many members is not necessarily an unsolvable problem; for example a basis for the vector space of functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that are non-zero at only finitely many points is certainly uncountable, yet I can easily write it down even inside this comment: It's given by the set of functions that are $1$ at exactly one point, and $0$ otherwise.